# ¿Cómo generar un archivo PDF que puede tener múltiples páginas según los detalles?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, itextsharp

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio que genera un archivo PDF *(a partir de una plantilla PDF)*.

El método que genera el PDF recibe estas dos variables de tipo `DataTable`:

`DataTable` tbl_template_variables:

[image: Primer DataTable]

`DataTable` tbl_details_invoice:

[image: Segundo DataTable]

Esta es la plantilla:

[image: Plantilla PDF]

Usando [itextsharp](/questions/tagged/itextsharp) uso este código para generar el PDF:

```
private void GenerateInvoice(DataTable tbl_template_variables, DataTable tbl_details_invoice)
{
    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(plantilla__Invoice__manual))
    {
        try
        {
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(location_output_file, FileMode.Create));
            AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

            // Loop DataTable and set the value in the specified field.
            for (int i = 0; i < tbl_template_variables.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                pdfFormFields.SetField(tbl_template_variables.Rows[i][0].ToString(), tbl_template_variables.Rows[i][1].ToString(), true);// set form pdfFormFields 
            }

            #region Diseño grid _Invoice_

            PdfPCell cell = null;
            PdfPTable table = null;

            table = new PdfPTable(9);
            table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
            table.SetWidths(new float[] { 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f });
            //table.SpacingBefore = 5;
            table.TotalWidth = 800f;

            for (int i = 0; i < tbl_details_invoice.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = tbl_details_invoice.Rows[i];
                object Invoice_PDFColumn0_value = row.Field<string>("PROVIDER") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("PROVIDER").ToString();
                object Invoice_PDFColumn1_value = row.Field<string>("DESCRIPTION") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("DESCRIPTION").ToString();
                object Invoice_PDFColumn2_value = row.Field<string>("PPTO") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("PPTO").ToString();
                object Invoice_PDFColumn3_value = row.Field<string>("JOB_MEDIA_TYPE") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("JOB_MEDIA_TYPE").ToString();
                object Invoice_PDFColumn4_value = row.Field<string>("VEND_INV_NO") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("VEND_INV_NO").ToString();
                //object Invoice_PDFColumn5_value = row.Field<string>("ORDER_MEDIA") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("ORDER_MEDIA").ToString();
                //object Invoice_PDFColumn6_value = row.Field<string>("ACTIVITY_MONTH") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("ACTIVITY_MONTH").ToString();
                object Invoice_PDFColumn7_value = row.Field<string>("COMMISSIONABLE") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("COMMISSIONABLE").ToString();
                object Invoice_PDFColumn8_value = row.Field<string>("NON_COMMISSIONABLE") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("NON_COMMISSIONABLE").ToString();
                string Invoice_PDFColumn9_value = row.Field<string>("IVA_PROVEEDOR") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("IVA_PROVEEDOR").ToString();
                string Invoice_PDFColumn10_value = row.Field<string>("TOTAL") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("TOTAL").ToString();

                //Columns table
                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn0.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn1.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn2.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn3.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn4.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                //cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn5.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                //table.AddCell(cell);

                //cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn6.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                //table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn7.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn8.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn9.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);

                cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(Invoice_PDFColumn10.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }

            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1));
            ct.AddElement(table);
            //iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(18, 370, 800, 36);
            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(16, 320, 900, 16);
            rect.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
            rect.BorderWidth = 15;
            rect.BorderColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
            rect.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
            ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
            ct.Go();

            #endregion

            // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
            // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
            pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
            pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = true;
            pdfStamper.Close();// close the pdf
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // No errors (yet).
        }
    }
}
```

Y este es un ejemplo del resultado que obtengo:

[image: Ejemplo resultado]

El problema que tengo es que cuando la información *que resalto en color ROJO en el ejemplo que adjunté* es mayor (es decir, hay mas de 4 filas), esta información se coloca en el PDF, pero no genera mas páginas.

Esto es porque cuando la información de la tabla "Detalles" se imprime, lo hace en unas coordenadas específicas.

¿Cómo puedo usar itextsharp para que "con la plantilla que estoy usando"<sup>1</sup> pueda generar un archivo PDF correctamente?

---

<sup>1</sup> Plantilla creada en Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por temas de tiempo y después de haber investigado en internet durante una semana, he llegado a esta solución que describiré en estos pasos:

- En lugar de seguir buscando cómo generar páginas al PDF en construcción, opté por crear X cantidad de archivos PDF *(con un nombre similar. Ejemplo: **PRUEBA_01.pdf**, **PRUEBA_02.pdf**, **PRUEBA03.pdf**, etc)*. Estos archivos serán temporales.
- Una vez creados los archivos PDF, uso el siguiente [código que encontré en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883360/4092887) para unir los archivos en uno solo.

Si alguien está interesado en cómo generar múltiples páginas en el archivo PDF en construcción, puede usar este código:

*Descripción: Crear 8 páginas en un archivo PDF, de tamaño A4, horizontal*:

```
string ruta_factura_generada = @"C:\Nueva Carpeta\PRUEBA.pdf";
Document doc = new Document();
PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, new FileStream(ruta_factura_generada, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();

double cantPaginas = 8; // Creará 8 páginas.

// En cada ciclo agregará una página "realmente es un rectángulo"
// con las medidas definidas del formato CARTA (LETTER) 
// "creo que es formato A4" - rotación horizontal.
for (int pagina = 0; pagina < cantPaginas; pagina++)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect1 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());
    rect1.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
    copy.AddPage(rect1, 0);
}

// Cierro el documento con los cambios realizados.
doc.Close();
```

---

Este es el [código que encontré en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883360/4092887) que une "o merge" los archivos PDF en un solo archivo PDF:

```
/// <summary>
/// Unir PDF's en un solo archivo.
/// Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883360/4092887
/// </summary>
/// <param name="fileNames">Lista con (las rutas de) los archivos.</param>
/// <param name="targetPdf">Ruta, nombre y extensión del archivo unificado a generar.</param>
/// <returns>bool</returns>
public bool MergePDFs(IEnumerable<string> fileNames, string targetPdf)
{
    bool merged = true;

    try
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
            PdfReader reader = null;
            try
            {
                document.Open();
                foreach (string file in fileNames)
                {
                    reader = new PdfReader(file);
                    pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                merged = false;
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (document != null)
                {
                    document.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        RegistrarEventosDelPrograma("Error al generar el archivo PDF unificado: " + ex.ToString(), "Error al generar el archivo PDF unificado");
        MessageBox.Show("Hubo un error al unir los archivos PDF" + SALTO_DE_LINEA +
            "Consulte el log de eventos de la aplicación para mas detalles.", TITULO, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    return merged;
}
```

En mi caso, necesitaba generar un archivo PDF que es básicamente un factura.

Allí, divido los resultados de la factura en bloques de 10 registros *(gracias a esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/200951/78))* y por cada bloque de 10 registros genero una página.

Este es el código que he ajustado para generar un archivo PDF unificado:

```
/// <summary>
/// Generar factura (archivo PDF).
/// Se generarán X cantidad de archivos "con nombres consecutivos" para al final 
/// del proceso, crear un archivo PDF con las hojas de los archivos "temporales".
/// Los archivos temporales son eliminados al finalizar.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="formFactura">DataTable con los valores de las variables de la plantilla.</param>
/// <param name="DetalleFactura">DataTable con el objeto JSON "ahora DataTable" - detalles.</param>
/// <param name="ruta_archivo_salida">Ruta y nombre del archivo PDF a generar.</param>
/// <returns>string</returns>
private string GenerateInvoice(DataTable formFactura, DataTable DetalleFactura, string ruta_archivo_salida)
{
    // Inicializar variables.
    string msg = "";
    List<string> rutas_archivos = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(plantilla_factura_manual))
        {
            try
            {
                // Crear X cantidad de archivos.
                // "PAGE_SEPARATOR" es el nombre de la columna que posee los valores separados por bloques.
                DataView view = new DataView(DetalleFactura);
                DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "PAGE_SEPARATOR");
                double cantPaginas = distinctValues.Rows.Count;
                for (int pagina = 0; pagina < cantPaginas; pagina++)
                {
                    using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(plantilla_factura_manual))
                    {
                        // Agregar la ruta del archivo temporal PDF a generar.
                        rutas_archivos.Add(ruta_factura_generada.Replace(".pdf", "(" + pagina + ").pdf"));

                        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(ruta_factura_generada.Replace(".pdf", "(" + pagina + ").pdf"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate));
                        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

                        // Llenar las variables de la plantilla en el archivo PDF en construcción.
                        for (int i = 0; i < formFactura.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            pdfFormFields.SetField(formFactura.Rows[i][0].ToString(), formFactura.Rows[i][1].ToString(), true);// set form pdfFormFields
                        }

                        #region Diseño grid factura

                        PdfPCell cell = null;
                        PdfPTable table = null;

                        table = new PdfPTable(9);
                        table.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                        table.SetWidths(new float[] { 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f, 22f });
                        //table.SpacingBefore = 5;
                        table.TotalWidth = 800f;

                        DataRow[] filas_a_usar = DetalleFactura.Select("PAGE_SEPARATOR = " + pagina);
                        foreach (DataRow r in filas_a_usar)
                        {
                            DataRow row = r;
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna0 = row.Field<string>("PROVIDER") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("PROVIDER").ToString();
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna1 = row.Field<string>("DESCRIPTION") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("DESCRIPTION").ToString();
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna2 = row.Field<string>("PPTO") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("PPTO").ToString();
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna3 = row.Field<string>("JOB_MEDIA_TYPE") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("JOB_MEDIA_TYPE").ToString();
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna4 = row.Field<string>("VEND_INV_NO") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("VEND_INV_NO").ToString();
                            //object valorFacturaPDFColumna5 = row.Field<string>("ORDER_MEDIA") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("ORDER_MEDIA").ToString();
                            //object valorFacturaPDFColumna6 = row.Field<string>("ACTIVITY_MONTH") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("ACTIVITY_MONTH").ToString();
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna7 = row.Field<string>("COMMISSIONABLE") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("COMMISSIONABLE").ToString();
                            object valorFacturaPDFColumna8 = row.Field<string>("NON_COMMISSIONABLE") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("NON_COMMISSIONABLE").ToString();
                            string valorFacturaPDFColumna9 = row.Field<string>("IVA_PROVEEDOR") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("IVA_PROVEEDOR").ToString();
                            string valorFacturaPDFColumna10 = row.Field<string>("TOTAL") == null ? string.Empty : row.Field<string>("TOTAL").ToString();

                            //Columnas table
                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna0.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna1.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna2.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna3.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna4.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            //cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna5.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            //table.AddCell(cell);

                            //cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna6.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            //table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna7.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna8.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna9.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);

                            cell = PhraseCell(new Phrase(valorFacturaPDFColumna10.ToString(), GettypeStyle()));
                            table.AddCell(cell);
                        }

                        ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(pdfStamper.GetOverContent(1));
                        ct.AddElement(table);
                        //iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(18, 370, 800, 36);
                        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(16, 320, 900, 16);
                        rect.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER | iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER;
                        rect.BorderWidth = 15;
                        rect.BorderColor = new BaseColor(0, 0, 0);
                        rect.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.BOX;
                        ct.SetSimpleColumn(rect);
                        ct.Go();

                        #endregion

                        // flatten the form to remove editting options, set it to false
                        // to leave the form open to subsequent manual edits
                        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;
                        pdfStamper.FreeTextFlattening = true;
                        pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = true;
                        pdfStamper.Close();// close the pdf
                    }
                }

                // Unir los archivos PDF's en uno solo.
                MergePDFs(rutas_archivos, ruta_archivo_salida);

                #region Eliminar archivos PDF temporales.

                try
                {
                    foreach (string archivo in rutas_archivos)
                    {
                        File.Delete(archivo);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    RegistrarEventosDelPrograma("Error al eliminar archivos PDF temporales: " + ex.ToString(), "Error al eliminar archivos PDF temporales");
                }

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg += "- Hay un error con la plantilla. Consulte el log de eventos." + SALTO_DE_LINEA;
                RegistrarEventosDelPrograma("Error al usar la plantilla (" + Path.GetFileName(plantilla_factura_manual) + "): " + ex.ToString(), "Error al usar la plantilla (" + Path.GetFileName(plantilla_factura_manual) + ")");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msg += "- Hubo un error inesperado al generar el archivo PDF. Consulte el log de eventos.";
        RegistrarEventosDelPrograma("Error al generar el archivo PDF. Detalles: " + ex.ToString(), "Error al generar PDF - Plantilla");
    }

    return msg;
}
```