# Actualizar bloques de filas en un DataTable - especificando el tamaño del bloque

Tags: c#

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio de tipo Windows en donde tengo una variable de tipo `DataTable` la cual puede poseer X cantidad de filas.

Para efectos de la pregunta, el `DataTable` se llamará: **items**.

He agregado una columna a la tabla **items** llamada **SEPARADOR** para que contenga el valor que defina la separación por bloques de filas.

Lo que busco es dividir las filas que pueda tener la tabla **items** en **bloques de 10 filas**.

Hay que tener en cuenta que el número de filas no siempre será exacto.

Ejemplo: la tabla **items** posee 24 filas, las filas están separadas cada 10 elementos con un número consecutivo *(en la columna **SEPARADOR**)*.

La tabla **items** debería quedar así:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|   Producto    |   Precio      |   SEPARADOR   |
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne           10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A1        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A2        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A3        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A4        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A5        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A6        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A7        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A8        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Carne A9        10000               0
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo           5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 1     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 2     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 3     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 4     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 5     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 6     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 7     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 8     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Pollo ZIP 9     5500                1
-------------------------------------------------
    Gaseosa         300                 2
-------------------------------------------------
    Gaseosa PIP 1   300                 2
-------------------------------------------------
    Gaseosa PIP 2   300                 2
-------------------------------------------------
    Gaseosa PIP 3   300                 2
-------------------------------------------------
```

He intentado usando if's para establecer la separación.

Ejemplo:

```
// Agregar separador de filas.
for (int r = 0; r < items.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    if (r >= 0 && r <= 10)
    {
        items.Rows[r]["SEPARADOR"] = 0;
    }
    if (r >= 11 && r <= 20)
    {
        items.Rows[r]["SEPARADOR"] = 1;
    }
    if (r >= 21 && r <= 30)
    {
        items.Rows[r]["SEPARADOR"] = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if (r > 30)
        {
            items.Rows[r]["SEPARADOR"] = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Pero esta no es la mejor opción porque el número de filas varía según la cantidad de datos que encuentre *(no siempre serán la misma cantidad de datos)*.

¿Cómo puedo lograr este resultado?

Comment: no entiendo lo que queres.. si haces r/10 te da el separador...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿puedes colocar un ejemplo?, no entiendo tu comentario.

Comment: Siempre es un separador cada 10 registros?

Comment: @gbianchi si, pero hay que tener en cuenta que no siempre se obtendrán bloques de 10 registros. En el ejemplo de mi pregunta hay 24 registros.

Comment: no importa el total.. siempre son grupos de 10?

Comment: @gbianchi si, es correcto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando un poquito de matematicas, cada grupo de 10 se encuentra dentro de un divisor de 10.

Por lo tanto, si los registros de 0 a 9 van al grupo 0, entonces que suerte, porque si dividimos cualquiera de esos numeros por 10, nos va a dar 0.

Los registros 10 a 19 van al grupo 1. que bueno porque si dividimos 10/10 da 1.. y si hacemos 19/10 da 1 tambien..

por lo tanto, simplifiquemos tu codigo a:

```
// Agregar separador de filas.
for (int r = 0; r < items.Rows.Count; r++)
{
    items.Rows[r]["SEPARADOR"] = r/10;
}
```